consuming Intent in Flutter
I come from the world of MAUI and my knowledge in Flutter is very limited, thats why I need your help! :D
I want to send a text from my MAUI app to my Flutter App using intent
I wrote this function in MAUI


public static async Task SendTextToFlutter()
{
    try
    {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
        sendIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionSend);
        sendIntent.SetAction("RECEIVE_INTENT_EXAMPLE_ACTION");
        sendIntent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, "text from MAUI");
        MainActivity.StartActivity(sendIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { };
}



and I followed the link https://pub.dev/packages/receive_intent#add-intent-filter-to-AndroidMainfest.xml and used the receive_intent in my flutter App


Future<void> _initReceiveIntent() async {
    // Platform messages may fail, so we use a try/catch PlatformException.
    try {
      final receivedIntent = await ReceiveIntent.getInitialIntent();
      // Validate receivedIntent and warn the user, if it is not correct,
      // but keep in mind it could be `null` or "empty"(`receivedIntent.isNull`).
      
    } on PlatformException {
      // Handle exception
    }
  }



when I run my MAUI app and Click the send buttun, the Intent fires and My flutter App is shown and I am happy with that! : )
But I dont know how to get the message that was sent along with the intent ""text from MAUI"" to be extracted and used further in Flutter.
Any help is appreciated
Cheers!

Not sure if I'd use a library for this or just program yourself, but did you take a look at this method? https://github.com/daadu/receive_intent/blob/master/lib/receive_intent.dart#L80 that should return a map with all the relevant data packageName, action... and 'extra' ;)

Thanks very much for pointing out, looks exactely what I am looking for, I will try that!
